# How to give a select statement as a condition to an IF block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM holiday)
THEN dbms_output.put_line('ok');
END IF;
END;
```

In the above code I am trying to print 'ok' if there are rows in 'Holiday' table. But i am getting an error.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

First select (i.e. check whether there's something in the table), then use its result in `IF`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select max(1)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from emp
  7      where rownum = 1;
  8
  9    if l_cnt is not null then
 10       dbms_output.put_line('ok');
 11    end if;
 12  end;
 13  /
ok

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```